# DIV and TEXTAREA elements interpreted 'width' CSS attribute differently?

Tags: html, css

Was a bit confused when the next HTML code

```
<div>Some text insize DIV</div>
<textarea>Some text insize TEXTAREA</textarea>
```

with CSS

```
div {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 25em;
}

textarea {
    width: 25em;
}
```

displayed DIV and TEXTAREA with the different width... what is the reason?

JSFiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j985xpmq/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`em`s are a measured based on the `font-size` and each of those elements have a different font size. The `div` is `font-size: 16px` and the `textarea` is `font-size: 11px` at least as a default in Chrome.

If you set the elements to the same `font-size` then they will be almost the same width. The remaining difference is because the `textarea` has padding and border too.

If you set the CSS to this, then the elements will be the same size:

```
div {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 25em;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
    width: 25em;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

because they will both have the same font-size, and the widths will be based on the border-box instead of the content-box, so padding and borders will be included in the width.

---

References:

- [font-size ems (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems)
- [box-sizing (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 2):

It's because those two elements have different default `font-size` properties and the `em` unit is based on the default font-size of whatever element you assign it to.

Here's a fiddle that shows the difference:

https://jsfiddle.net/j985xpmq/1/

Here's a fiddle that shows them the same:

https://jsfiddle.net/j985xpmq/4/

You'll notice that I removed padding from the `textarea` and added a border to the `div`

Answer (score 1):

To further prove zfrisch's correct answer, this is almost equal:

```
div {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 25em;
   font-size:14px;
}

textarea {
    width: 25em;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Where the default font-scaling is maintained the same for each element, and the `<textarea>` box also features default padding so is still a very slightly different size from the div width, but they are very close now.

https://jsfiddle.net/j985xpmq/3/

Comment: This is why I included `box-sizing` in my answer :)

Comment: @CodingWithSpike I did not see your edited answer until I had posted mine, but yes, I saw your box-sizing and I thought "good call". :-D